# WordPress in glassfish upload theme error

Tags: php, wordpress, glassfish

I have managed to install wordpress in glassfish server.
Now I want to update themes and plugins...
But when I try to upload a new theme, this is what I am getting

> The uploaded file could not be moved to
>   /usr/local/glassfish-3.1.2.2/glassfish/domains/admin/docroot/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/01.

I've tried changing permission to 775, 777,

changed owner to root, glassfish, www-data, no-body.

increased upload file size limit to 10mb, increased memory limit, post size limit, etc etc etc...

I've tried almost everything mentioned in the discussion about this in google.

Is there anything else I need to do to make this error go away ?

By the way, glassfish is running under "glassfish" user

Answer (score -1):

Wordpress is a PHP application, GlassFish is a Java EE application server. GlassFish contains no capability to run PHP. What you are attempting will not work.

Edit: Note that there was an old project attempting to implement PHP on GlassFish, but it had not been updated in years the last time I checked. It certainly won't support the latest versions of Wordpress.

Comment: I successfully implemented wordpress 3.7 in glassfish using quercus

Comment: That's a very important bit of information you missed out of your post. Please update your question with the output of the GlassFish server log when you get that error. The path looks strange for GlassFish, though. Have you created a new domain called `admin` or is it just a folder within `domains`?

Comment: Sorry I missed out admin from my answer... updated my amswer

Answer (score -1):

Since I successfully installed wordpress in glassfish, I am giving my own answer....

These are the requirements 
Glassfish 3.1.2.2
Quercus latest version
Wordpress 3.7 ( latest version 4.7 will not work ) so do not upgrade....

Procedure:
Unzip wordpress.zip to domains/admin/docroot/wordpress

Sudo chown -R glassfish:glassfish wordpress

Comment: Is this actually an answer to your question, or are you just adding background to your question?